# Finding the position of the first character of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Please help, I have a column (`range varchar(11)`) with values like `'422000'`, `'357860'`.

I need a query that can change the first character position (i.e 4 and 3) to 5.

so that it becomes `'522000'` and `'557860'`, respectively.

I tried:

```
select replace (SUBSTRING(range,1,1), 1,5))
```

but this is not the correct query.

I would appreciate your contribution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [STUFF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188043%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for this:

```
DECLARE
    @range varchar(11);
SET @range = '422000';

SELECT @range, STUFF(@range, 1, 1, '5');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Range],
       '5' + SUBSTRING([RANGE],2,25) [ModifiedRange]
FROM   (SELECT '422000' [Range]
        UNION
        SELECT '357860') A
```

Comment: Realized a flaw in my answer was it replaced ALL occurences of the first number with `5`, not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This option will replace the first letter no matter the length of range

```
Select range, '5' + SUBSTRING(range, 2, LEN(range)) as fixedrange
```

The associated Update statement (that will change data in your table) would be:

```
Update tbl_name SET range = '5' + SUBSTRING(range, 2, LEN(range))
```